# Unable to login SQL Server and Reset SA password Error 18456

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2017

Very strange scenario that I encounter.

[image]

Pretty sure that I am using an administrator account to perform the installation.

[image]

I try to command prompt to start stop the service and still see the same error message. Is there anything I need to verify ?

Thanks.

Comment: as part of installation, did you add the admin user as SA ?

Comment: The `State` numbers supplied in the client-side error messages are invalid for security reasons. Find the instance's `ERRORLOG` file, find the error `18456` messages and compare the `State` numbers shown in there against those published at [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error). If there are no error messages in the log file it likely means you're not actually connecting to that SQL Server instance successfully, so: is the service running; are firewalls helping; has the SQL Browser service restarted?